# Is there a list of all available extensions for Jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, npmjs, jupyter-lab

I am looking for a webpage or some manner to see a list of the existing extensions for Jupyterlab. I have been manually browsing through the [www.npmjs.com](http://www.npmjs.com) with the search keyword @jupyterlab. Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I think the best way to find extensions is to visit https://github.com/topics/jupyterlab-extension

Comment: https://github.com/mauhai/awesome-jupyterlab

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can see a list of jupyterlab extensions by browsing the `jupyterlab-extension` topic on github ([as suggested](http://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) by the jupyterlab docs):

https://github.com/topics/jupyterlab-extension

Answer (score 5):

Found in Jupyterlab tutorial Documentation -> Release 0.1 ->
Chapter 2.2 -> Installation extension.

The currently installed extensions can be listed by running 
the command: `jupyter labextension list`.

Comment: This returns the list of installed extensions. I think the question is a master list of extensions that are available to install.

Comment: I needed this command to verify INSTALLED extensions for Jupyter Classic Notebook and JupyterLab, and had a very hard time finding it.  This is the first place I ran across it.  I like the fact that the author give the source.  I don't think the author of this answer deserved 4 downvotes, so I am upvoting this.